# Ingress on GKE. Run specify service healthcheck

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I try to use ingress for loadbalancer of 2 services on Google Kubernetes engine:

here is ingress config for this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: basic-ingress

spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: web
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /v2/keys
        backend:
          serviceName: etcd-np
          servicePort: 2379
```

where web is some example service from google samples:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    run: web
  type: NodePort

----
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: web
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
```

But the second service is ETCD cluster with NodePort service:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: etcd-np
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 2379
    targetPort: 2379
  selector:
    app: etcd
  type: NodePort
```

But only first ingress rule works properly i see in logs:

```
ingress.kubernetes.io/backends: {"k8s-be-30195--ebfd7339a961462d":"UNHEALTHY","k8s-be-30553--ebfd7339a961462d":"HEALTHY","k8s-be-31529--ebfd7339a961462d":"HEALTHY"}
```

I etcd-np works properly it is not a problem of etcd , i think that the problem is that etcd server answers with 404 on GET / request and some healthcheck on ingress level does not allow to use it .

Thats why i have 2 questions :

1 ) How can I provide healthcheck urls for each backend path on ingress

2 ) How can I debug such issues . What I see now is

```
kubectl describe ingress basic-ingress
Name:             basic-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          4.4.4.4
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (10.52.6.2:8080)
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *           
              /*         web:8080 (10.52.8.10:8080)
              /v2/keys   etcd-np:2379 (10.52.0.2:2379,10.52.2.4:2379,10.52.8.4:2379)
Annotations:  ingress.kubernetes.io/backends:
                {"k8s-be-30195--ebfd7339a961462d":"UNHEALTHY","k8s-be-30553--ebfd7339a961462d":"HEALTHY","k8s-be-31529--ebfd7339a961462d":"HEALTHY"}
              ingress.kubernetes.io/forwarding-rule: k8s-fw-default-basic-ingress--ebfd7339a961462d
              ingress.kubernetes.io/target-proxy: k8s-tp-default-basic-ingress--ebfd7339a961462d
              ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map: k8s-um-default-basic-ingress--ebfd7339a961462d
Events:       <none>
```

But it does not provide me any info about this incident

**UP**

```
kubectl describe svc etcd-np

Name:                     etcd-np
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              Selector:  app=etcd
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.4.7.20
Port:                     <unset>  2379/TCP
TargetPort:               2379/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30195/TCP
Endpoints:                10.52.0.2:2379,10.52.2.4:2379,10.52.8.4:2379
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Comment: share output of kubectl describe svc etcd-np

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu : I have added it to the post

Comment: I have also LoadBalancer service to test etcd - it is configured the same way as NodePort and it works fine

Comment: From where this etcd came from? GKE etcd is hidden and we don't have access to it.

Comment: @mWatney - no etcd comes from third-party image. In this case it is just example of the service that does not answer with 200 on / page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#health_checks).

> A Service exposed through an Ingress must respond to health checks
>   from the load balancer. Any container that is the final destination of
>   load-balanced traffic must do one of the following to indicate that it
>   is healthy:
>
> 1. Serve a response with an `HTTP` `200` status to GET requests on the `/` path.
> 2. Configure an `HTTP` readiness probe. Serve a response with an `HTTP` `200` status to `GET` requests on the path specified by the readiness
>      probe. The Service exposed through an Ingress must point to the same
>      container port on which the readiness probe is enabled.
>
> For example, suppose a container specifies this readiness probe:
>
> ```
> ...
> readinessProbe:
>   httpGet:
>     path: /healthy
> ```
>
> Then if the handler for the container's `/healthy` path returns an
>   `HTTP` `200` status, the load balancer considers the container to be
>   alive and healthy.

Now since ETCD has a health endpoint at `/health` the readiness probe will look like

```
...
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /health
```

This becomes a bit tricky if mTLS is enabled in ETCD. To avoid that check the [docs](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/master/Documentation/op-guide/monitoring.md#health-check).